# What is the sed command in Debian's /etc/init.d/umountfs supposed to do?

Tags: sed

`/etc/init.d/umountfs` is run during shutdown to unmount most filesystems. It contains this:

```
PROTECTED_MOUNTS="$(sed -n ':a;/^[^ ]* \(\/\|\/usr\) /!{H;n;ba};{H;s/.*//;x;s/\n//;p}' /proc/mounts)"
```

This command apparently selects a subset of the lines in `/proc/mounts`, which then become exempt from being unmounted later in the script.

It matches lines with `/` or `/usr` in the second field (the mount point) and then what it does next involves too many exotic sed features for me to figure out what the intent is.

It would make sense if this was just selecting the `/` and `/usr` lines, since those get unmounted in a different script. But it doesn't do that. When I run it on my actual `/proc/mounts`, `$PROTECTED_MOUNTS` ends up containing almost all the lines, including the `/home` line. It's not good if `/home` doesn't get unmounted, so that can't be right.

What could the writer of that sed command possibly have meant to do, with all that branching and hold space stuff?

Comment: Whatever they meant to do, it's quite ugly if you ask me... I mean, leaving the picket fence aside and the fact that it doesn't use `ERE` though the syntax assumes `gnu sed`, why doing  `n;ba` ? Isn't that the same as simply using `b` or even better, `d`? And `H` when _either... or..._ ? Why not using it only once, at the top of the script, so that it applies to all lines ?  [[:shrugs:]]

Comment: The first sentence of the question is wrong.  **`/etc/init.d/umountfs` is not run at all**, at startup or shutdown, by default in Debian, **from Debian 8 onwards**.  It is masked by a symbolic link at `/lib/systemd/system/umountfs.service`.

Comment: And as I already pointed out in this Q&A, don_crissti, Debian bug #655582 has the explanation of what this was meant to do.

Comment: @JdeBP I'm not sure that applies to those of us still successfully resisting systemd. Or to the first shutdown after an upgrade. And the sed command in bug #655582 doesn't include the `/usr` part which is new in Debian 9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll give it a shot...

This will return every line up to and including the *last* occurrence of `/` *or* `/usr`. AKA this strips everything after the last occurrence of either of those.

```
:a;/^[^ ]* \(\/\|\/usr\) /!{H;n;ba};
```

This says, for lines that don't contain exactly `/` or `/usr` in the second (whitespace delimited) column, append to `H`old space, fetch `n`ext line, loop `b`ack to label `a`.

```
{H;s/.*//;x;s/\n//;p}
```

We'll only get here if we encounter a line with `/` or `/usr`. Then we append to `H`old space (which has everything from the first section), clear pattern space, e`x`change hold space with pattern space, remove first newline from pattern space and `p`rint it.

After we've seen the last `/` or `/usr` line (and we've printed everything up to that point), we loop through the first part and suck all the remaining non-matching lines up...but they never get printed since we don't enter the second part.

I did a bit of testing and that has been consistent with my claim.

---

Clearly this depends on some kind of ordering being maintained in `/proc/mounts`. But the list is simply built according to [the order that the mount points are created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5426818/ordering-of-proc-mounts-and-etc-mtab). So wherever that is done must be maintained or this stuff will break, I guess. It all seems awfully brittle to me.

Comment: Psst!  Debian bug #655582 has the explanation.

Comment: So the assumptions are: 1. `/proc/mounts` is in some predictable order (which I always thought was not true); 2. in whatever order that is, all the "real" filesystems other than the root are below the last `/usr`

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley I got curious about the ordering. I added a link to a Q&A about that.